# With Spring-MVC, how can we filter HTTP POST form parameters based on user role?

Tags: forms, security, spring, spring-mvc

I have forms to edit users in a web application. If the user role is a director, I want them to be able to edit all the properties on a user object using the form. However, if the user role is a medium-level role and not a director, I only want them to edit most/some of the properties on the user object - but not others.

Of course it's easy to hide the html markup for the fields I don't want them to edit if they are not a director, but this is not secure enough. How do I tell spring MVC to FILTER the http post parameters and not set them on the form backing object when the user role is something other than a Director? Can I do this? I know I can use @InitBinder as a "catch all" case, but I don't think I can use this on a per-request basis... can I?

I know Rails just recently added this feature in their latest versions of their framework, so I would not be surprised if Spring did not have it. Is it easy to achieve this with Spring?

If there's no built-in framework support for this, what is the easiest way to go about it? Create an entirely new type for the form backing object and just do manual copying of all of the fields during an update? That seems kind of bloated and not very maintainable when I want to add new fields... But I can't think of any other solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Submitting / binding partial objects with spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794509/submitting-binding-partial-objects-with-spring-mvc)

Seems like having classes to represent the different forms with different subsets of the User class's properties is likely the simplest way to go. At least you don't have to manually copy the properties over one at a time, as you can use:

[BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object destination)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of what I thought. Glad to know there's at least a function to sort of simplify the process. Still seems heavy though. :(